# Office.js for Word 2016 Mac

Tags: office-js

Are Office.js Api available for developing Mac word 2016 add-in ?
Microsoft github documentation indicates it's available, but blogs mentions it's expected in early 2016

Answer (score 3):

It is currently available on the Word 2016 for Mac. Here's a [sample that has been tested on Word 2016 for Mac](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-SillyStories). Here are the steps for installing a manifest on the Mac:

1. Create a folder called “wef” in Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Documents/
2. Put the manifest in the wef folder (Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Documents/wef)
3. Open Word 2016 on the Mac and click on the Insert tab > My Add-ins drop down. You should see the add-in listed in the drop down. Select it and it will load the add-in.

Comment: I installed Office 2016 on Mac version 15.19.1 (160212). I do not see "My Add-ins" option under insert menu

Comment: After upgrading to latest 15.20 or restarting word, "My Add-ins" is visible now.   Do you have similar sample for Excel 2016 Mac ? I tried https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Task-Pane-Add-in-Calculator by copying Calculator.xml to Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef/ , but it did not work.

Comment: That sample should work on the mac. You should open a new post and give your repro steps, point to the resources you've tried, and specify any error messages.

Comment: Using Word 15.22.1, add-ins that are in the wef folder are not listed as installable on my system (osx). Looking for a solution.

Comment: Found a solution to my issue. I pointed the xml manifest to a file path, and I needed to set up a testing server and point the xml to the ```http://127.0.0.1:port/whatever.html``` file.