# How do you get a Word add-in to show in Mac Word 2016?

Tags: macos, office-js

I am trying to follow the basic proof-of-concept office.js / add-in for Mac Word 2016.

I can see the ability to add add-ins, but none of my manifests show.

Reference: [Office.js for Word 2016 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221392/office-js-for-word-2016-mac#).

The instructions call for putting the xml in a folder named "wef"...here's the path to MY wef:
/Users/11trees/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/wef

All the instructions suggest the following path (so no specific username):
Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Documents/wef

Maybe I'm missing something totally obvious...or perhaps the difference in location isn't the reason my manifests aren't showing.

The manifests I'm using are the Boilerplate and SillyStories examples from the web - verbatim.

Thank you for any help.

Updating with Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
    <Id>0e978793-8a1a-43c9-b8bb-762db69bdfae</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>11trees</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Boilerplate content" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Insert boilerplate content into a Word document." />
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Document"/>
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://127.0.0.1:8080" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Same problem here. Cannot see my add-ins and don't know why. Using the boilerplate sample. Don't really see what op did to fix it in his case. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/Users/11trees/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/wef is the correct path for 11trees.

When you select the Insert tab > My Add-ins, are you selecting the button or the drop down portion of the button? The add-in should be listed in the drop down. If not, there is a chance that there is an error with the manifest. Can you post your manifest here?

**Update 6/6**: it looks like the comment is causing the manifest to not be registered by Word. When I removed the comment in the SillyStories manifest, I could see the add-in in the drop down.

The boilerplate content manifest is working fine for me with version 15.22 (160501)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added one of the 2 manifests I've got in wef. Right out of the sample. I don't see any options in a drop down - I'm choosing Insert/Add-ins/My Add-ins...a modal comes up and it doesn't find anything. I can switch to developing on Windows...but I'd rather not:)

Comment: What build of Word are you using? If you select the drop down, does it look like this: http://imgur.com/1spycIf. Instead of selecting the My Add-ins button, can you select drop down. It should look somewhat like the image I provided.

Comment: Michael, thank you so very much...really, really dumb answer on my part...apologies for wasting your time. I was looking in the Insert/My Add-ins menu choice -  from the main File/Edit/View...menus.

I did not read the instructions to suggest you went to the Insert RIBBON tab...and now of course I see my local manifests. Many thanks.

Comment: If you're unblocked, then no time wasted. :)